# Read and combine data from multiple csv files

Tags: python, sorting, csv, pandas

I have 3 different files: NewRush4.csv, NewRush5.csv, NewRush6.csv. 
I am trying to collect an 'All-Time Leaders' from each Season (4, 5, and 6).

I want to either read every player's name in every file and combine them if they are duplicates, or read the first file and compare it with the other two files to combine them.

Here is my python code. I have to read the first file. I'm not sure how to go about using DictReader.

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import csv
file = open("NewRush4.csv", "rb")

for line in csv.DictReader(file, delimiter=","):
    name = line["Player"].strip()
    yds = line["YDS"].strip()
    car = line["CAR"].strip()
    td = line["TD"].strip()
    fum = line["FUM"].strip()
    ypc = line["YPC"].strip()

    print "%-20s%10s%10s%10s%10s%10s" % (name, car, yds, td, fum, ypc)
file.close()
```

Output:

```
49erswag                     3      14.0         0         0       4.7  
A Beast Playa                7      23.0         0         0       3.3  
A Swanky Guy 2              29     154.0         1         2       5.3  
ACIDRUST                     1       4.0         0         0       4.0  
Aj dahitman                227    1898.0        19         2       8.4  
Aldizzl                     10      45.0         0         0       4.5  
Areis21                     13      58.0         0         2       4.5  
at43                        48     214.0         1         1       4.5  
Ayala2012xTCU               57     195.0         0         1       3.4  
B O R Nx 25                 13      31.0         0         1       2.4  
B r e e z yx60               4      13.0         0         0       3.3  
Beardown74                 116     621.0         6         3       5.4  
beatdown54 2010             26     126.0         3         1       4.8  
behe SWAG                    1      -5.0         0         0      -5.0  
Big Murph22                 73     480.0         6         2       6.6  
BigBlack973                 18      57.0         0         1       3.2  
BiGDaDDyNaPSacK            184    1181.0        20         4       6.4
```

Season4 File:

```
Player,YDS,TD,CAR,FUM,YPC  
49erswag,   14.0,   0,   3,   0,   4.7  
A Beast Playa,   23.0,   0,   7,   0,   3.3  
A Swanky Guy 2,   154.0,   1,   29,   2,   5.3  
ACIDRUST,   4.0,   0,   1,   0,   4.0  
Aj dahitman,   1898.0,   19,   227,   2,   8.4  
Aldizzl,   45.0,   0,   10,   0,   4.5  
Areis21,   58.0,   0,   13,   2,   4.5  
at43,   214.0,   1,   48,   1,   4.5  
Ayala2012xTCU,   195.0,   0,   57,   1,   3.4  
B O R Nx 25,   31.0,   0,   13,   1,   2.4  
B r e e z yx60,   13.0,   0,   4,   0,   3.3  
...
```

Season5 File:

```
Player,YDS,TD,CAR,FUM,YPC  
a toxic taz,   307.0,   4,   44,   0,   7.0  
AbNL Boss,   509.0,   4,   174,   2,   2.9  
AFFISHAUL,   190.0,   0,   35,   2,   5.4  
AJ DA HITMAN,   1283.0,   19,   228,   6,   5.6  
allen5422,   112.0,   2,   18,   0,   6.2  
Allxdayxapx,   264.0,   1,   76,   2,   3.5  
AlpHaaNike,   51.0,   1,   10,   1,   5.1  
Aura Reflexx,   215.0,   1,   40,   0,   5.4  
AWAKEN DA BEAST,   -5.0,   0,   4,   1,   -1.3  
AxDub24,   -3.0,   0,   2,   1,   -1.5  
Ayala2012xTCU,   568.0,   4,   173,   1,   3.3  
BALLxXHAWKXx,   221.0,   1,   47,   2,   4.7   
BANG FIGHTY007,   983.0,   6,   171,   3,   5.7  
bang z ro,   29.0,   0,   9,   0,   3.2  
BEARDOWN74,   567.0,   6,   104,   2,   5.5  
...
```

So, if a player played in more than one season, add his stats and print. Otherwise, just print.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [collections.defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict):

I don't know what each field mean; I sum each field. Adjust as your need.

```
from collections import defaultdict
import csv

class PlayerStat(object):
    def __init__(self, yds=0, car=0, td=0, fum=0, ypc=0, count=0):
        self.yds   = float(yds)
        self.car   = float(car)
        self.td    = float(td)
        self.fum   = float(fum)
        self.ypc   = float(ypc)
        self.count = count
    def __iadd__(self, other):
        self.yds   += other.yds
        self.car   += other.car
        self.td    += other.td
        self.fum   += other.fum
        self.ypc   += other.ypc
        self.count += other.count
        return self

filenames = 'NewRush4.csv', 'NewRush5.csv', 'NewRush6.csv',
stats = defaultdict(PlayerStat)
for filename in filenames:
    with open(filename) as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f, delimiter=',')
        for row in reader:
            stat = PlayerStat(row['YDS'], row['CAR'], row['TD'], row['FUM'], row['YPC'], count=1)
            stats[row['Player']] += stat

for player in sorted(stats, key=lambda player: stats[player].yds):
    stat = stats[player]
    if stat.count == 1:
        continue
    print '{0:<20}{1.car:>10}{1.yds:>10}{1.td:>10}{1.fum:>10}{1.ypc:>10}'.format(player, stat)
```

Comment: I just realized one file did not have the headers. But this worked beautifully! I want to sort this by YDS now, would that be as simple as stats.sort(lambda X: x[2]) ?

Comment: @user2556506, I updated the code sorted by YDS. `sorted(stats, key=lambda player: stats[player].yds)`

Comment: Thanks falsetrue! this has been SOO helpful I can apply this to everything now! :) I can't tell you how long this has taken me!

Answer (score 0):

You can try with python pandas, seems like the tool you need. For the reading part, you can go with [read_csv](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html), then create three `DataFrame` (or one, with all the records), and further manipulate on them.

For duplicates, for instance, you might try the `duplicated` [function](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html#pandas.DataFrame.duplicated), going, e.g., with `df[ df.duplicated('Player') ]`. You will also find there plenty of [descriptive statistics](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/basics.html) functions, such as `max` that you might probably need. Have a look.

To give you the taste (based on Season4 and Season5 data in the original post):

```
import pandas as pd

if __name__ == '__main__':

    # reading in is very convenient here:
    df_4 = pd.read_csv('season4.csv')
    df_5 = pd.read_csv('season5.csv')
    # combine the two DataFrames into one:
    df   = pd.concat([df_4, df_5], ignore_index=True)
    # see how it looks:
    print df.head(50)

             Player   YDS  TD  CAR  FUM  YPC
0          49erswag    14   0    3    0  4.7
1     A Beast Playa    23   0    7    0  3.3
2    A Swanky Guy 2   154   1   29    2  5.3
3          ACIDRUST     4   0    1    0  4.0
4       Aj dahitman  1898  19  227    2  8.4
5           Aldizzl    45   0   10    0  4.5
6           Areis21    58   0   13    2  4.5
7              at43   214   1   48    1  4.5
8     Ayala2012xTCU   195   0   57    1  3.4
9       B O R Nx 25    31   0   13    1  2.4
10   B r e e z yx60    13   0    4    0  3.3
11      a toxic taz   307   4   44    0  7.0
12        AbNL Boss   509   4  174    2  2.9
13        AFFISHAUL   190   0   35    2  5.4
14     AJ DA HITMAN  1283  19  228    6  5.6
15        allen5422   112   2   18    0  6.2
16      Allxdayxapx   264   1   76    2  3.5
17       AlpHaaNike    51   1   10    1  5.1
18     Aura Reflexx   215   1   40    0  5.4
19  AWAKEN DA BEAST    -5   0    4    1 -1.3
20          AxDub24    -3   0    2    1 -1.5
21    Ayala2012xTCU   568   4  173    1  3.3
22     BALLxXHAWKXx   221   1   47    2  4.7
23   BANG FIGHTY007   983   6  171    3  5.7
24        bang z ro    29   0    9    0  3.2
25       BEARDOWN74   567   6  104    2  5.5 

    # see for duplicated entries in the 'Player' column:
    print df[ df.duplicated('Player') ]

           Player  YDS  TD  CAR  FUM  YPC
21  Ayala2012xTCU  568   4  173    1  3.3

    # see for the maximum value in the 'YDS' column:
    print 'Max YDS:', df['YDS'].max()

Max YDS: 1898.0
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: @user2556506 I wrote a code snippet to give u a better feeling of things.

Comment: Thanks! This makes sense! Don't know why I didn't find pandas earlier!